# Phase factor when deriving expressions for up/down spin in the $z$-basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

From what I understand, spin in the x direction takes the form $$ |+\rangle_x = a|+\rangle + b |-\rangle $$ (in the z basis), where $a$ and $b$ are complex. You can work out the value of the constants $a$ and $b$ (which is $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $) from using the results attained in the Stern Gerlach experiment.

During the derivation of spin in the x direction, I understand that a phase factor is added since the constants can be complex, however why is this added to only one of the terms (in this case the $ |-\rangle $ co-efficients).

$$ |+\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle+e^{i\alpha}|-\rangle)$$
$$ |-\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle-e^{i\beta}|-\rangle)$$

(where $ \alpha $  and $ \beta $ are constants)

Comment: Mixing bra and ket vectors doesn't make much sense.
You probably mean $|+\rangle_x$ and $|-\rangle_x$
instead of $\langle+|_x$ and $\langle-|_x$.

Comment: Apologises, I have corrected it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.
$|+\rangle_x$ and $|-\rangle_x$ must be orthogonal to each other.
Therefore $e^{i\alpha}$ and $e^{i\beta}$ cannot be the same.

Comment: Yes they are not, they are different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an overall phase to a quantum state doesn't change anything.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|+\rangle+ e^{i \alpha}|-\rangle\right)$ is the same as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e^{i \delta}|+\rangle+ e^{i (\alpha + \delta)}|-\rangle\right)$, up to an overall phase. So we can freely set $\delta = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of arbitrary if you apply the factors
to the $|+\rangle$ or to the $|-\rangle$ components.

Instead of defining
$$\begin{align}
|+\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle+e^{i\alpha}|-\rangle) \\
|-\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle+e^{i\beta}|-\rangle)
\end{align} \tag{1}$$
you could as well define
$$\begin{align}
|+\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{-i\alpha}|+\rangle+|-\rangle) \\
|-\rangle_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{-i\beta}|+\rangle+|-\rangle)
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

The vectors $|+\rangle_x$ from (1) and (2) differ only
by an over-all phase factor $e^{2i\alpha}$.
This is irrelevant to the physics.
They are physically the same state.